# How do I save an image with a label on it to the photo album?

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview

Im making a camera app and I want to add a label to the pictures that are taken like in the app MSQRD and save to the photo album. I got the label to display on to the image but when I go to the photo album it shows an image but without the label. What am I doing wrong with my code. Here is the code that Im using currently:

```
@IBAction func takePicture(sender: AnyObject) {


if let videoConnection = stillImageOutput!.connectionWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo) {
            videoConnection.videoOrientation = AVCaptureVideoOrientation.Portrait
            stillImageOutput?.captureStillImageAsynchronouslyFromConnection(videoConnection, completionHandler: {(sampleBuffer, error) in
                if (sampleBuffer != nil) {

                    let imageData = AVCaptureStillImageOutput.jpegStillImageNSDataRepresentation(sampleBuffer)
                    let dataProvider = CGDataProviderCreateWithCFData(imageData)
                    let cgImageRef = CGImageCreateWithJPEGDataProvider(dataProvider, nil, true, CGColorRenderingIntent.RenderingIntentDefault)
                    let image = UIImage(CGImage: cgImageRef!, scale: 1.0, orientation: UIImageOrientation.Right)




        //edited this part it saves the entire view in the photo album except for the image that was taken and the label. 
       UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.view.bounds.size, self.view.opaque, 0.0)
                    self.view.layer.renderInContext(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!)
                    let newImage: UIImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
                    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()




                    //saves captured picture to camera roll.
                    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(newImage, nil, nil, nil)





                    //fade in the image that was taken
                    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, delay: 0.1, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveLinear, animations: {

                        self.capturedImage.image = image
                        self.capturedImage.alpha = 1.0

                        }, completion: nil)
                        }
                        }
                        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You made the `capturedImage` from `UIGraphicsImageContext`, but never used. Change `UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image, nil, nil, nil)` to `UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(capturedImage, nil, nil, nil)`.

Comment: I tried that already using calturedImage.image and it saves a black image in the photo album.

Comment: I edited my code in the op. I got everything in the view to save in the photo album except for the captured image and label.